# Python recursion function to print tree structure resets variable in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I wish I could explain my problem better, but I simply don't know why my code is not working. I suspect it has to do with scoping, but my searches haven't availed me of a clear solution. I'm generally a Javascript/Java programmer, so perhaps you can understand my confusion.

```
def ls(directory, times=None):
    if times is None:
        times = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for dirname in dirs:
            print('    ' * times + dirname)
            ls(dirname, times + 1)
        for filename in files:
            print('    ' * times + filename)
```

Which should ideally print any given directory structure like so:

```
a
    b
        c
    d
    e
```

However, the space indents aren't included because for some reason, subsequent recursive calls to ls() show that the variable times is reset to 0 in the for loop for os.walk(directory). Why is that variable being "reset"?

Comment: What is `ls_walk`?

Comment: typo. Let me edit that.

Comment: `os.walk` is already recursive, so it doesn't make any sense to write another recursive function on top of it. If you need to write a recursive function and reinvent the `os.walk` wheel, probably for a homework assignment, try `os.listdir` and recurse on every directory that yields.

Comment: I'm a little confused, because `os.walk` is already providing the recursive walk. What you need to know is the depth at any given iteration, which you can figure out by comparing `root` with `directory`.

Comment: I'm less interested in solving the problem of printing the directory structure than I am in figuring out what's happening to the variable.

Comment: @Dennis Your recursive call attempts to walk a non-existent directory (`dirname` instead of `os.path.join(root, dirname)`), so nothing is ever printed where `times != 0`. `os.walk` hides the error by default.

Comment: This is not even an issue related to the variable. The whole point is just that `os.walk`.

Comment: @hmm You are right. Mark solved or close?

Comment: Close? There are already a lot of posts about how os.walk works.